# Assigning outgoing interface for UDP packet on linux/android without root

Tags: android, linux, sockets, routes

I'm trying to assign an outgoing interface for a UDP packet without root.

So far I've found

1. IP_PKTINFO which will modify the source address, but the interface selection will still be based on the routing table
2. SO_BINDTODEVICE which will work but requires root
3. modification to the routing table which will require permissions I do not have.

I've found IP_NEXTHOP on Solaris, but apparently it is not in Linux.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this functionality in API level 22

[**bindSocket**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#bindSocket%28java.net.Socket%29)

void bindSocket (DatagramSocket socket)

> Binds the specified DatagramSocket to this Network. All data traffic
>   on the socket will be sent on this Network, irrespective of any
>   process-wide network binding set by bindProcessToNetwork(Network). The
>   socket must not be connected.

You request a network using this

[**requestNetwork**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#requestNetwork%28android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

void requestNetwork (NetworkRequest request, 
                PendingIntent operation)

> Request a network to satisfy a set of NetworkCapabilities. This
>   function behaves identically to the version that takes a
>   NetworkCallback, but instead of ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback a
>   PendingIntent is used. This means the request may outlive the calling
>   application and get called back when a suitable network is found.
>
> The operation is an Intent broadcast that goes to a broadcast receiver
>   that you registered with registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver,
>   IntentFilter) or through the  tag in an AndroidManifest.xml
>   file
>
> The operation Intent is delivered with two extras, a Network typed
>   extra called EXTRA_NETWORK and a NetworkRequest typed extra called
>   EXTRA_NETWORK_REQUEST containing the original requests parameters. It
>   is important to create a new, ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
>   based request before completing the processing of the Intent to
>   reserve the network or it will be released shortly after the Intent is
>   processed.
>
> If there is already a request for this Intent registered (with the
>   equality of two Intents defined by filterEquals(Intent)), then it will
>   be removed and replaced by this one, effectively releasing the
>   previous NetworkRequest.
>
> The request may be released normally by calling
>   releaseNetworkRequest(android.app.PendingIntent).
>
> It is presently unsupported to request a network with either
>   NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED or NET_CAPABILITY_CAPTIVE_PORTAL as these
>   NetworkCapabilities represent states that a particular network may
>   never attain, and whether a network will attain these states is
>   unknown prior to bringing up the network so the framework does not
>   know how to go about satisfing a request with these capabilities.
>
> This method requires the caller to hold either the
>   CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE permission or the ability to modify system
>   settings as determined by canWrite(Context).

So if you request a network that is currently available, you can bind a socket to it.